# shortest progam to scan a line and print it using befunge!

Tags: code-golf, befunge

well, I'm newly introduced to [befunge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befunge).
it seems to be an amazing language but a bit hard to start with! anyway after about 2 hours of hard work I've created a code which could read a line from stdin and write same line into stdout(I'm using line -1 as buffer in this code):

```
0> :~:a-#v_$$v vg-10:-1< >$>:#,_@
 ^+1p-10\<   >0>\:    #^_^
```

since I'm new to this language I wanted to know if there is a shorter code to do such a thing.
I'm currently using [Rc/funge-98 v2 interpreter](http://www.rcfunge98.com/v2.html). note that none-trailing whitespaces are counted in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since it seems no one could create 7 character program, here is what I did. it works at least with befunge!

### Befunge, 7

```
~:,a`j@
```

Comment: @ajax333221 here is my code.

Comment: but this does not output the newline.

Comment: @marinus that's no big deal, just putting "," at the third character will solve that! the whole idea is to use "j" instead of "!#@_"

Answer (score 6):

## Befunge-98, 4

`~,#@`

[Try it online!](http://befunge-98.tryitonline.net/#code=fiwjQA&input=cmFjZWNhcg)

It works because `~` acts like `r` when there is no more input (credit to [David Holderness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62101/james-holderness) for finding [this](https://github.com/catseye/Funge-98/blob/master/doc/funge98.markdown#standard-inputoutput) in the funge-98 spec)

Answer (score 2):

### Befunge, 10

```
~:,a`!#@_
```

You were thinking a bit too hard about it I think :)

Comment: now I see what you did there, it seems to be complete answer. I was going to later use input string to parse as a "single precision floating point", which seems to be not possible using your method.

Comment: the only reason I'm not accepting your answer is because I know an answer of 7 characters.

Comment: @Gajet [you should post it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: @ajax333221 I want to give other people opportunity to get 15 rep.